# Android app crashes when calling glVertexAttribPointer

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm trying to create an app with OpenGL ES integration on Android.
My app seems to crash when I call `glVertexAttribPointer`.

Renderer class:

```
public class Renderer implements  GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    int matrixHandle=0;
    int positionHandle=0;
    int colorHandle=0;

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.7f,0.7f,0.7f,1.0f);

        try{
            loadShaders(matrixHandle,positionHandle,colorHandle);
        }catch(RuntimeException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        GLES20.glViewport(0,0,width,height);
        float ratio = (float)width/height;
        float left=-ratio;
        float right=ratio;
        float bottom=-1.0f;
        float top=1.0f;
        float near=1.0f;
        float far=10.0f;
        float[] projectionMatrix=new float[16];
        Matrix.frustumM(projectionMatrix,0,left,right,bottom,top,near,far);
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        float[] mVMatrix = new float[16];
        float camX=0.0f;
        float camY=1.0f;
        float camZ=1.0f;
        float lookX=0.0f;
        float lookY=0.0f;
        float lookZ=0.0f;
        float upX=0.0f;
        float upY=1.0f;
        float upZ=0.0f;
        Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix,0,camX,camY,camZ,lookX,lookY,lookZ,upX,upY,upZ);
        Grid floor =new Grid(positionHandle);
    }

    public void loadShaders(int matrix, int position,int color){
        String vShader = "uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix;\n"
                +"attribute vec4 a_Position;\n"
                +"attribute vec4 a_Color;\n"
                +"varying vec4 v_color;\n"
                +"void main(){\n"
                +"  v_color=a_Color;\n"
                +"  gl_Position = u_MVPMatrix*a_Position;\n"
                +"}";
        String fShader = "precision mediump float;\n"
                +"varying vec4 v_Color;\n"
                +"void main(){ gl_FragColor = v_Color; }";
        int vertexShader=GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        if(vertexShader!=0){
            GLES20.glShaderSource(vertexShader,vShader);
            GLES20.glCompileShader(vertexShader);
            int[] compileStatus=new int[1];
            GLES20.glGetShaderiv(vertexShader,GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS,compileStatus,0);
            if(compileStatus[0]==0){
                GLES20.glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
                vertexShader=0;
                throw new RuntimeException("Error creating vertex shader.");
            }
        }
        int fragShader = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        if(fragShader!=0){
            GLES20.glShaderSource(fragShader,fShader);
            GLES20.glCompileShader(fragShader);
            int[] compileStatus = new int[1];
            GLES20.glGetShaderiv(fragShader,GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS,compileStatus,0);
            if(compileStatus[0]==0){
                GLES20.glDeleteShader(fragShader);
                fragShader=0;
                throw new RuntimeException("Error creating fragment shader.");
            }
        }
        int ProgramHandle=GLES20.glCreateProgram();
        if(ProgramHandle!=0){
            GLES20.glAttachShader(ProgramHandle,vertexShader);
            GLES20.glAttachShader(ProgramHandle,fragShader);
            GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(ProgramHandle,0,"a_Position");
            GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(ProgramHandle,1,"a_Color");
            GLES20.glLinkProgram(ProgramHandle);
            int[] linkStatus= new int[1];
            GLES20.glGetProgramiv(ProgramHandle,GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS,linkStatus,0);
            if(linkStatus[0]==0){
                GLES20.glDeleteProgram(ProgramHandle);
                ProgramHandle=0;
                throw new RuntimeException("Error unable to link shaders.");
            }
        }
        matrix=GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(ProgramHandle,"u_MVPMatrix");
        position=GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(ProgramHandle,"a_Position");
        color=GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(ProgramHandle,"a_Color");
        GLES20.glUseProgram(ProgramHandle);
    }
}
```

Grid class:

```
public class Grid {
    int size=50;
    float[] color={1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f};
    int positionHandle=0;
    int colorHandle=0;
    int matrix=0;
    public Grid(int pos){
        //for(int i=-(size+1);i<size;i++){
            float[] vertices={
                0.0f,0.0f,-1.0f,
                0.0f,0.0f,1.0f
            };
            ByteBuffer vertexBuffer=ByteBuffer.allocate(vertices.length*4);
                vertexBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            FloatBuffer fVertexBuffer=vertexBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
            fVertexBuffer.put(vertices);
        fVertexBuffer.position(0);
                //loadShaders(matrix,positionHandle,colorHandle);
            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(pos);
            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(pos,2,GLES20.GL_FLOAT,false,0,fVertexBuffer);
            GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_LINES,0,2);
            GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(pos);
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error/exception?

Comment: I'm using AIDE on android so I dont have a debugger attached to the program.

Comment: I used a third party logcat reader and I see the error aaying "new GraphicBuffer needed". Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch of stuff wrong/missing in the posted code. Not sure if this will cover everything, but it should give you a start:

1. Java passes method arguments by value. So this call:

   ```
   int matrixHandle=0;
   int positionHandle=0;
   int colorHandle=0;
   ...
       loadShaders(matrixHandle,positionHandle,colorHandle);
   ```

   will **not** assign values to the 3 variables. The values will be assigned to the local function arguments inside the method implementation, but not returned back to the caller.
2. Somewhat similar problem in `onSurfaceChanged()`. Here you calculate a projection matrix:

   ```
   float[] projectionMatrix=new float[16];
   Matrix.frustumM(projectionMatrix,0,left,right,bottom,top,near,far);
   ```

   but it is only stored in a local variable. The value will be lost as soon as the method returns.
3. At least in the posted code, I don't see a value set for the `u_MVPMatrix` uniform anywhere.
4. There are no values set up for the `a_Color` attribute.